# Wrong output when using a large input

Tags: c++, c

Okay, this is the code for an easy question I was trying to do [from Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/KOL1506). The question was simple but for some reason I am getting a wrong answer when using a large input, but correct ones for a small input.

**Example**

When I assign `houses` to `10` and `k` to `2`, I am getting the correct amount, but when keep the houses the same and use `k=10` I would receive a wrong answer.

**My code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){

    int houses[1000],k,numberofhouses;
    int sum=0,tmpsum=0;
    int i,j,d;

//  printf("enter number of houses\n");
    scanf("%d",&numberofhouses);

//  printf("enter k\n");
    scanf("%d",&k);

//  printf("enter distance\n");

    for(i=0;i<numberofhouses;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&houses[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<(numberofhouses-1);i++) {
        for(j=i+1;j<numberofhouses;j++) {
             d = ( houses[i] - houses[j] );
             tmpsum = pow(abs(d),k);
             sum = sum + 2 * tmpsum;
        }
    }

    printf("sum is %d",sum);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Java, C or C++? Seems to be C. So adjust your tags.

Comment: you know that int is usually 32 bit and maximal value around ~2kkk?

Comment: The problem specifies that the result should be given modulo 1000000007, which could have been a clue to you, but which you neglect to mention or implement.  You are looking for [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) to avoid overflowing your temporaries or losing precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for a wrong ouput when using a large input is the `tmpsum= pow(abs(d),k);` line, because of the overflow.

For larger values the result of `pow(a,b)` is more than the `int` data type can bear.

Try changing your data type to `long long int`.

Since even `long long int` will not work for you. You need to implement your own pow function.

```
long long int mypow(int a,int b) {
    if(b == 0)
        return 1;
    if(b == 1)
        return a;
    if(b%2)
        return (((a*mypow(a*a,b/2)))%(1000000007));
    return((mypow(a*a,b/2))%(1000000007));
}
```

Comment: You're right that the intermediate results can be too large for an `int`.  Unfortunately, they can be too large for `long long int`, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : You are right. But i saw the link given in question. Maximum value of `d` can be `10^5` and `k` can be `100` he `long long int` is not enough to store the values required. He needs to implement his own `pow()` function in which he can take `%` at each step. `Pow(a,b)` can be implemented in `O(log(b))`.

Comment: @Shravan40 i get that library function pow will not work for me here so i implemented my own pow function using simple recursion but still getting wrong output. and also can u tell me how is your mypow function is working. i am not getting the significance of three base function and and use of b%2. thank you for your help.

Comment: @happysharma: I am checking whether `b` is `even` or `odd` and multiplying accordingly.

Comment: @Shravan40 if i m not wrong you are calculating exponential by using exponentiation by squaring ?

Comment: @happysharma: Yes correct.

Comment: @happysharma: If your query has been resolved, please accept the answer.